# How to insert xml node in vb.net

Tags: xml, vb.net

Actually I have an xml file with a child node and it's working fine. I want to insert a new child node like, Xml name: product.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Table>
  <product>
    <name>1</name>
    <name1>2</name1>
    <name2>3</name2>
    <name3>4</name3>
    <name4>5</name4>
  </product>
  <!-- I want to insert <product> node with its parameter here -->
</Table>
```

I tried below code and got null reference exception ,Please refer below   and guide me,

```vb
Dim xmlDoc As XmlDocument = New XmlDocument()    
xmlDoc.Load("product.xml")

DimcourseName = "1"

With xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("/Table/product[pid = '" & courseName & "']/Table").CreateNavigator().AppendChild()
  .WriteStartElement("product")
  .Close()
End With
```

Comment: Did you show your actual XML structure? Your XPath query suggests you didn't.

Answer (score 0):

This is how you append an XML node in VB:

```vb
Dim x = XDocument.Load("product.xml")

x.<Table>.First().Add(<product/>)
```

Instead of `.First()` that selects the first `<Table>` it finds you can provide a query that selects a more appropriate Table, e.g.

```vb
Dim table = (From t In x.<Table> Where t.@id = "1").First()
table.Add(<product/>)
```

Or in the functional syntax:

```vb
x.<Table>.Where(Function(n) n.@id = "1").First().Add(<product/>)
```

Comment: not able to use ur above code , can u please expain in detail

Comment: The above is the complete code. There is nothing to explain apart from [the syntax](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384629.aspx).